# Limit on SQL conditional operators?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a limit to how many conditional operators I can use in PHP to query a mySQL database?

This is my scenario: I download the local MLS board's listings from their database into my own database using RETS (real estate transaction standard).

There are two tables, one with the listing information and another one with Open House information. All local brokerage's listings are included in both of these tables. We are only interested in our own brokerage's open houses.

Unfortunately there is no identifier for which agent or which brokerage the open house is for in the openhouses table, there is only a `Unique_ID` that I can cross reference with the listings table.

My approach is to scan through the listings table and get the `Unique_ID`s of ONLY our brokerage listings and use each `Unique_ID` as a conditional operator in the SQL query in the openhouses table (ie. `where Unique_ID = "10101" || Unique_ID = "10102"` etc).

We service a relatively small area so there could be anywhere between 1-50 openhouses at any given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay You need to show some code but ... here's what you need to so with out knowing anything.

1. make sure your database tables are properly indexed
2. use a join

Example

```
Select `listing_tbl`.*
    FROM `open_house_tbl`
         INNER JOIN `listing_tbl` ON `listing_tbl`.`unique_id` = `open_house_tbl`.`unique_id`
                AND `listing_tbl`.`brokerage_id` = 'X'
    WHERE `open_house_tbl`.`open_house_date` >= NOW()
    ORDER BY `open_house_tbl`.`open_house_date` ASC
```

Comment: This exactly what I was looking to do, but didn't know how to do it! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a limit on the size of a query - defined in the DBMS config - but you're not going to get anywhere near that. OTOH embedding the predicates in the SQL statement does not scale well - with large numbers of cases the query will be very inefficient - a better solution would be to put them in a table and do a join.